# How to render accents in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying render an element which has an accent character using `ReactJS` and JSX, but it's not returning what I wanted.

My JSX:

```
var Orcamento = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Orçamento</h1>

            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <Orcamento/>,
    document.getElementById("orcamento")
);
```

My rendered javascript:

```
var Orcamento = React.createClass({displayName: "Orcamento",
    render: function() {
        return (
            React.createElement("div", null, 
                React.createElement("h1", null, "Orçamento")

            )
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    React.createElement(Orcamento, null),
    document.getElementById("orcamento")
);
```

And my result in browser:

```
OrÃ§amento
```

I've set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my index file inside the `head` tag, accent characters works in page title and body if this word is typed direct in page content, but is not working when it's rendered by `ReactJs`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I just copied your code and made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/h2k2ksm3/. It works there as you'd expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you see, `OrÃ§amento`, is the result of a UTF-8 byte array being rendered in ASCII, probably codepage ISO [8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

ReactJS doesn't support non-ASCII characters within HTML.

Try this:

```
var Orcamento = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> { 'Orçamento' } </h1>

            </div>;
        );
    }
});
```

Or simply replace `Orçamento` with `Or&#231;amento`.

This is well explained in the [JSX gotchas](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html).

Comment: I'm tried using <h1>{ 'Orçamento' }</h1>, but is not working too, and "Or&#231;amento" maybe is not a good way for me, because if my page language is Portuguese Brazilian, I can't put this code every time when has accents

Comment: I see. Did you make sure the encoding of the JSX file is UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, JSX file and jsx compiled js file is UTF-8

Comment: I tried set charset for "iso-8859-1"  and "utf-8" in meta tag, and set browser detect encode automatic, but is not working too

Comment: Where is it documented that ReactJS doesn't support non-ASCII characters? That's not on the page you referenced, and my simple demo from the code in the OP works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/h2k2ksm3/.

Answer (score 10):

I resolved! the problem is because I'm compiling `JSX` using `gulp`, and file generated is not `UTF-8`, so I save as file in `UTF-8` that is working!

Comment: That worked for me. I edited my component files with notepad and saved as in utf-8.

Comment: If you are using VS code or similar, change the project or file codification to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Also using the charset utf-8, try using this library: 
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

```
import { decode } from 'he';

class Post extends Component { 
  render() {
    <h1>{ decode(this.props.post.title) }</h1>  
  }
}
```