# Reactjs not showing åäö swedish charactes nspite of utf-8 encoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, utf-8, ascii

I'm using reactjs on a Swedish site and having trouble getting Swedish characters Å Ä Ö to show. Right now they are just shown as �... I really don't want to have any strange plugins or libraries to fix this!

I am using react-create-app and my `index.html` file has

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in it's header.

I can't figure out what else to do.

I can't use ascii characters everywhere since the content is dynamic with lots of data being passed to and from a database... having to use ascii everywhere makes things really difficult. Why does this not work out of the box???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render accents in ReactJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472020/how-to-render-accents-in-reactjs)

Comment: What does the server send as the HTTP response header Content-Type for index.html? (Use F12 dev tools in your browser of choice.)

Comment: @TomBlodget where do I find the Content-Type in Chrome 58? Can't seem to find it anywhere...

Comment: Hit F12. Click Network. Navigate to index.html. In the list, select index.html after it is loaded. Click the Headers tab. Look under Response Headers for Content-Type, it may or may not be present. If present, it will override the meta tag. charset may or may not be present in the Content-Type header.

Comment: The Content-Type is not present :(

Comment: Edit the component files with notepad (if Windows) and save them as in utf-8.

Comment: I have the same problem.. Did you manage to find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, it was the encoding of the file. Opened it in notepad and saved as utf-8.